# 2d character array printing wrong results

Tags: arrays, printing

Thank you in advance for all of the incredible responses on the board.

I'm trying to print the 2d array to display the characters as they are arranged there, but instead of the characters, I am only getting:

```
4 6
4 6
4 6
4 6
4 6
4 6
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The array size and string came out just fine…

source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char list_ch[][2] = {
    '1', 'a',
    '2', 'b',
    '3', 'c',
    '4', 'd',
    '5', 'e',
    '6', 'f' };

int i, j;

int main() {

    printf("List_ch size:%d\n", sizeof list_ch);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            printf("%c ", list_ch[i, j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("This is the string:\n");
    printf("%s", list_ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag the language you're using

Comment: I'm guessing C. Disambiguation would be nice. :)

Comment: Seems to be [running fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/aIejjPU.png). What language / complier / Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Printing command should be changed to

```
printf("%c ", list_ch[i][j]);
```